# Is there a way to generate builder using the antlr4 grammar?

Tags: antlr, grammar, stringbuilder, parse-server

I understand that one could generate lexer and parser given the antl4 grammar but Is there a way to generate builder using the antlr4 grammar? That way client can use the builder to construct the possible structure specified in the grammar while the server can use the generated parser to parse the structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is, yes. Such a sentence generator can walk the ATN and create sentences according to the grammar (see my [antlr4-vscode extension](https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4/blob/master/src/backend/SentenceGenerator.ts) of how this can be implemented). However, unless you have a very simple grammar with no recursions or iterations, you will probably not be able to generate a fixed set of sentences, since there are infinitive possible combinations.

Comment: I definitely have recursions. Why not generate recursive builder code?

Comment: I explained it already: you can create some variations, but with recursions/iterations you may have a variable number of sub elements which will result in infinite combinations.

Comment: how do i do this in Java ? just use antlr4 library?